# searching through a 2 dimentional array.

Tags: java

I have this method that Determines whether the square on the board at a given row and column is under attack by any queens in the columns 1 through column-1. but i i keep getting an exception error on **board[row-column+y][y] == QUEEN**

```
  private boolean isUnderAttack(int row, int column)
  {
            for (int y=0; y<column; y++)
            {
             if (board[row][y] == QUEEN ||    // possible horizontal attack
             board[row-column+y][y] == QUEEN ||   // diagonal NW
             board[row+column-y][y] == QUEEN)     // diagonal SW

             return true;
            }

            return false;
  }
```

Comment: What exception? ArrayIndexOutOfBounds? You should provide more info, but the problem is(most probably) quite clear. From the indices in the exception you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: In the NW test if the Square in question has a low row, low y and a high column values you'll end up with a negative index.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attetion to:

```
row + column - y
```

This operation can return a number lesser than 0.

Your class should be like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Board {

private final int[][] board;
private final int dimention;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Board p = new Board(6);
    for (final int[] i : p.board) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
    }
    p.isUnderAttack(2, 3);
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    for (final int[] i : p.board) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
    }

}

public Board(final int dimention) {
    this.dimention = dimention;
    this.board = new int[dimention][dimention];
}

private void isUnderAttack(final int row, final int column) {

    for (int y = 0; y < this.dimention; y++) {
        this.board[y][row] = 1; // possible horizontal attack
        this.board[column][y] = 2; // possible vertical attack
    }
    int staringRow = column - row;
    int y = 0;
    do {
        this.board[staringRow][y] = 3; // diagonal SW
    } while ((++staringRow < this.dimention) && (++y < this.dimention));

    int staringCol = column + row;
    int x = 0;
    do {
        this.board[x][staringCol] = 4; // diagonal NW

    } while ((++x < this.dimention) && (--staringCol < this.dimention));
}

}
```

This is the output of this test:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]



[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4]
[3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0]
[0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2]
[0, 4, 1, 3, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks...not what i was looking for. but gave me an idea